# vaadin flow grid get row in edit state

Tags: grid, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am using a grid in vaadin flow. When it is a row in edit state I would like to get the row index of the grid.
I guess I have to use the following but I can't make it.

```
   grid.getEditor().isOpen();
   grid.getEditor().getItem()
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could look up the item in your grid's collection:

```
grid.getEditor().addOpenListener(event -> {
    System.out.println("Opened editor on item " + myItems.indexOf(event.getItem()));
});
```

Although the 'index' will be the index in that collection rather than the index in the displayed grid, which is influenced by the sort order and filtering. I believe that not exposing an index on the `EditorOpenEvent` is intentional, as the concept of an index is presentation specific and abstracted away from the server-side initialization of the grid.

If you really needed to get to the index of the row in the current grid presentation (which respects sort order), you could make a Javascript call. Given this isn't part of the documented API, it's likely subject to change.

```
PendingJavaScriptResult pendingJavaScriptResult = grid.getElement().executeJs("return this._focusedItemIndex");
pendingJavaScriptResult.then(jsonValue -> {
    System.out.println("From JS:" + jsonValue.asNumber());
});
```